# glGenLists and iOS

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, ios

It is possible use Display Lists (glGenLists) on iOS? I'm doing some openGL ES for iPhone platform and I want gain more performance so i think that Display List was a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

I fear they are not, at least not in [OpenGl ES specification 1.0](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/1.0/opengles_spec_1_0.pdf)

> **5.4 Display Lists**
>
> Display lists are not supported. Display lists are used
> by many applications—sometimes to
> achieve better performance and
> sometimes for convenience. The
> implementation complexity associated
> with display lists is too large for
> the implementation targets envisioned
> for this profile.